# Comparator return type is not compatible with integer

Tags: java, sorting, debugging, comparator

I am trying to sort an object via the object attribute NodeID which is long type.

```
 Collections.sort(PeerNodeInChord, new Comparator<PeerNode>() 
       {
           @Override public long compare(PeerNode p1, PeerNode p2) 
           {
                 return p1.NodeID - p2.NodeID; // Ascending
           }

       });
```

I am getting the following error :

> compare(PeerNode,PeerNode) in  cannot implement
>   compare(T,T) in Comparator   return type long is not compatible with
>   int   where T is a type-variable:
>       T extends Object declared in interface Comparator

It seems i cant have type "long" as return type and must have "int" as the return type.

I am not allowed to change NodeID type to int.

Is there any way to sort the ArrayList of PeerNode via the object attribute NodeID which is long type ??

Answer (score 6):

Don't reinvent the wheel and simply delegate to the `compare` method from `Long`:

```
@Override 
public int compare(PeerNode p1, PeerNode p2) {
    return Long.compare(p1.NodeID, p2.NodeID);
}
```

Out of curiosity, you can give a look to the `Long.compare` implementation which is:

```
public static int compare(long x, long y) {         
    return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);     
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Collections.sort(PeerNodeInChord, new Comparator<PeerNode>() {
    @Override 
    public int compare(PeerNode p1, PeerNode p2) {
        long dif = p1.NodeID - p2.NodeID;
        if (dif > 0) return 1;
        if (dif < 0) return -1;
        return 0; 
    }
});
```